# Refining regex to match anything after

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to match numbers that could appear in common ordinances
such as:

```
101.2.23.1 Door Clearances
```

I have this regex that matches numbers and multiple dots:

```
^[.?\d]+$
```

However, I need to allow all the text that appears afterwards.  Also, this returns false positives for ordinal lists like `1. 2. 3. 4.`.

Is there a way I can match anything with at least 3 numbers in the beginning and any text afterwards?

Here are examples of what exactly I expect to (not) match:

```
101.1              => true
101                => false
1.                 => false
101.1.1 Clearances => true
```

Comment: What did you mean by *returns false positives for ordinal lists*?

Comment: I didnt want it to match things like 1. 2. 3. 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\d{3}\..+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rTEC_TNjGBcL2SVR) (with tests for all the sample inputs provided)

Key points:

- `^` – beginning of the input string
- `\d{3}\.` – three digits followed by a period
- `.+` – "any text afterwards"
- `$` – end of the input string

Note that in your original pattern `^[.?\d]+$`, `.` will literally match `.` and `?` will literally match `?` because these characters appear in a character class (beginning with `[` and ending with `]`) – not what you intended I expect.

Comment: This works great thanks for the demo too, I'll mark this as answer when it the time restraint allows me

Comment: Just realized this one doesnt mat 101.2 DoorClearances Sorry I should have been more clear it just has to be 3 numbers in the beginning with a dot and all text afterwards is optional

Comment: @johnny5: I edited my answer to align with the updated explanation you provided.

Comment: Thanks yours is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

^(\d+.?)+\s(.*)$

First group are one or more pairs of  (last dot optional) and second group matches the rest

Comment: Yes, 3 0) A general one 2) The numbers, 3) The text. If you want only the text, you can change the groups to non capturing ones (?:\d+.?) for the first one

Comment: You right this works the best but it does not match 3 numbers in the beginning

Comment: Do you want to capture the three numbers (1.1.1) plus the text ? This would need two capture groups. Do you want to restrict the numbers match to only three ? Can you give an example of the ideal match ?